# Spotfire-IronPython: Fetch visualization from Document.Pages

Tags: ironpython, spotfire

Say I have a loop through every page is Spotfire, how can I fetch the visualization per page?

```
for pg in Document.Pages:
    print pg.Title
    myPanel = pg.ActiveFilteringSelectionReference
    print '\t' + myPanel.Name
    # How to fetch vis from a Page? Assume each page has only one visualization
    viz=vis.As[ScatterPlot]()
```

Best Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
#loop through all pages and visualizations, and print the Type of each visualization
for p in Document.Pages:
   print (p.Title)
   Document.Properties["scriptOutput"]+=p.Title+'\n'
   for v in p.Visuals: 
      print ('-' + v.Title + '('+ v.TypeId.Name +')')
      Document.Properties["scriptOutput"]+='-'+v.Title+'('+v.TypeId.Name+')\n'
```

You have to set up Document Properties to show the results, unless you are in the console and reading the output.

Please see this page for more information: https://community.tibco.com/wiki/loop-through-pages-and-visualization-tibco-spotfirer-using-ironpython-scripting